# PHPUnit Version issue and Mock Builder

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I am facing a version issue with phpunit . When I execute 
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
I get an error: phpunit/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.5.15  install failed

But when I execute phpunit --version, I get
PHPUnit 3.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

I do not understand what is happening here. I stumbled on the issue when all of my mock builder functions (setMethod(), getMockBuilder()...etc) threw a undefined method fatal errors and I figured that these methods are only available in 3.5 and up.

All your help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on some flavor of Unix/Linux, what does `which phpunit` report? This should hopefully lead you to your second installation. You can start by renaming the file returned by `which`.

Comment: Hello. I did this and it points to the installation with 3.4.5 and not the latest. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Great, so you can either remove the script it points to, uninstall 3.4.5, or reference the latest version's script with absolute path. Either way, hopefully you can get the latest version up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to upgrade your `pear` version. It should be 1.9.4 (or higher) to work properly.

Try `pear update pear` and once `pear version` shows 1.9.4 try `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit`. It that doesn't help use `--force --alldeps` arguments.

That should to the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this and I am stuck with the same issue.

Comment: @user960002 What output to you get from `pear version` and did you check if it reports any error messages while installing (like 'channel pear.phpunit.de needs to be upgrade type pear channel-upgrade ... ` and so on) ?